# I need to fetch data from database but I need the result in this form of {data,data,}

Tags: php

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/connection.php';
  $data = "select * from contacts_tbl";
  $query_posi = mysqli_query($con, $data);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_posi)){
    echo $row['contact_number'];
  }
?>
```

the result of that is `09277432079 09236677868`

What result I want is `{09277432079,10236677868}`

Comment: Are you looking for a JSON format result or is it exact `{09277432079,10236677868}` ?

Comment: {09277432079,10236677868} i need it like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a loop over your contacts array to demo the concept of visiting those data in a while loop and echoing contacts comma separated and wrapped in parenthesis:

https://onlinephp.io/c/6280d

```
$contacts = [
    '09277432079',
    '10236677868',
    '10436674963',
    ];

$arrayLength = count($contacts);
$i = 0;
echo '{';
while ($i < $arrayLength)
{
    echo $contacts[$i];
    if($i < $arrayLength-1)
        echo ',';
    $i++;
}
echo '}';
```

Comment: <?php
require_once 'includes/connection.php';
$data = "select * from contacts_tbl";
$query_posi = mysqli_query($con, $data);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_posi)){
        $contacts = $row['contact_number'];
    }
    $arrayLength = count($contacts);
    $i = 0;
    echo '{';
    while ($i < $arrayLength){
        echo $contacts[$i];
        if($i < $arrayLength-1)
            echo ',';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '}'; 
?>
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\WLMS\arduino_getData.php on line 8
{0}

Comment: it depends on the php version because count() doesn't work on the newer versions (I've been using it max on 5.4) ... I added a demo on purpose so it couldn't be told it didn't work. Anyway I see there's no much margin to move if not using exactly that array and looping on that database cursor. Good luck. The concept was clearly shown on how to loop the array and how to decide to echo the separators and the wrappers. It doesn't take too much effort to tailor it on your scenario.

Comment: Thank I've already figured it out because of your help. Thanks, @everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable with "{" as the initial value and then concatenate the iterations to your variable. Finally concatenate with "}".

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/connection.php';
  $data = "select * from contacts_tbl";
  $query_posi = mysqli_query($con, $data);
  $result = "{";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_posi)){
    $result.= $row['contact_number'].",";
  }
  //Delete the last comma
  $result = substr($result,0,1);
  $result.="}";
  echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: no result fund result is {}